Does every homomorphism of quotients algebras lift to a free algebra homomorphism?
Let $A$ and $B$ be free $k$-algebras and $X$ and $Y$ some quotient algebras of the respective free algebras.
Assume that we have a unital morphism of the quotient algebras $X \rightarrow Y$. Can it always be lifted to a unital (!) morphism of the respective free algebras $A \rightarrow B$?
I can see that of course there are maps $A \rightarrow B$ that are NOT even algebra morphisms but descend to algebra morphisms $X \rightarrow Y$, but do not know how to see the 'other direction'.
I would appriciate also any counter examples or hints!

This holds for every algebraic theory (groups, Lie algebras, etc.). Just apply the universal property of $A$. Please try that and then write where you get stuck. Unital or not doesn't matter, because again: the theory doesn't matter.

Ah, I think I see. As the map $Y \rightarrow B$ I can choose fixing arbitrary representatives of the quotient classes. Composing, this gives a map from the set of generators of $A$ to $B$. Then by the universal property of $A$ it lifts to a proper morphism?

Yes. I suggest that you post an answer then. It is OK, in fact encouraged to answer own questions. Also removes them from the unanswered list. By the way you are using the axiom of choice here.
